# Struggling with installing Celery for Tornado

Tags: celery, tornado

So, I am trying to test Celery with Tornado, but having difficulty with Celery installation.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I have ad Tornado working for months now. Then tried to install Celery using `python -m pip install tornado-celery`. But my import commands in test script don't work.

For example, I get an `ImportError: unable to locate tasks` when I do `import tcelery, tasks`.

So, I tried to uninstall Celery thinking something went wrong. Tried `apt-get remove tornado-celery`. I get an error saying `Unable to locate package tornado-celery`. So, I re-install and then it says `Requirement already satisfied`.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

`tasks` isn't a module that comes with celery - the idea of that example is that you'd write your own file `tasks.py` to put your tasks in. There's an example of this in https://github.com/mher/tornado-celery/tree/master/examples

Your installation is fine (as far as I can tell), but if you do want to uninstall it, use the same program to uninstall as you did to install: something installed with `pip install` can only be uninstalled with `pip uninstall`, not `apt-get uninstall`.